# Excel - matching to multiple criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, multiple-conditions

I have a list of shops with annual sales. These shops have each been assigned a discount code.

The discount code is based on sales but is fixed within a range.
For example,
all shops that sell up to 999 could have a discount code of either 1,2,or 3.
shops that sell between 1,000 - 2,000, they could have a code of 4, 5 or 6. and so on.

I am trying to get a formula that would check the sales in one cell, check the discount in another cell, and then return say 'correct Band' if the discount code is correct for the amount of annual sales, and if not, it would return 'incorrect band'.

So for example, using the figures above
Shop 1: sales 1,500, assigned discount code = '5', formula should return 'Correct Band'
Shop 2: sales 600, assigned discount code = '4', formula should return 'Incorrect band'
Shop3: sales 750, assigned discount code = '3', formula should return 'Correct Band'

I have tried so many different things, but none work. I have tried IF, AND.......IF,OR......tried nested ISNUMBER(SEARCH.........
Some seem to work, but generally my problem is that I cannot find a way to specify that Band 2 should be greater than or equal to 1000.........so when I put in <1000 for band 1 and <2000 for band 2 and I get a shop which has sold 1400 but has been assigned a discount code of 3, I am unable to pick it up in my formula.

Hope the above makes sense and sorry it is so wordy.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's an idea to create a table with the values (A) and their codes (B) and match the values from your list with this table `INDEX([NewTable]B:B,MATCH([ListValue],[NewTable]A:A,1))` and check if the outcome matches the code from your list or not.

Comment: @ user14618570 - thanks......... when googling this question, I saw a suggestion to use the INDEX function, but I just didn't understand. Your explanation is clear, and I will try it as well. For now, I have gone down the nested IF route, but thanks for taking the time to respond........... I was really in a fix and you guys saved my life!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have correctly understood your problem, I'd say sometihng like this, using nested if

```
if(and(sales<1000;discount code<=3);"correct band";if(and(sales>=1000;sales<2000;discount code>3);"correct band";"wrong")
```

this hould work if the discount code is in a numeric format, otherwise either you turn it into a number or you edit the above code in

Clearly when I mean "sales" and "discount_code" i mean the cells in the corresponding columns

```
if(and(sales<1000;or(discount_code="1";discount_code="2";discount_code="3"));"correct band";if(and(sales>=1000;sales<2000;or(discount_code="4";discount_code="5";discount_code="6"));"correct band";"wrong")
```

try and let me know

Comment: Thanks Ale, your nested 'IF' statement is very close to what I had. The mistake I made was after my OR, I did (discount code = 1,2,3) instead of (discount code = 1, discount code = 2 etc.)......... so thanks - your response solved my problem!!! Thanks again!!

Comment: Finally, someone closed this question saying it was not specific enough.......... two people were able to read the question and provide solutions that worked. I had tried to google this and realised there were a number of ways it could be solved. I wanted to leave the options open to get a variery of answers, which is exactly what happened, I got an IF solution and an INDEX solution. I feel the question was was specific, the choice of answer left open, so I'm not sure why it was closed especially as others read it and understood the requirement.

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate that it hellped